# ¿Por qué la primera entrada de "como" es la que está en desuso? Más generalmente, ¿cómo se elige el orden de las entradas del diccionario?

Tags: definiciones, rae, dle

Resulta que si buscas "como" en el DLE te encuentras con dos resultados:

> [**como**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWAAKF)<sup>1</sup>; [**como**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9)<sup>2</sup>

La primera es:

> [**como**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWAAKF)<sup>1</sup>
>   `Del gr. κῶμος kômos 'fiesta con cantos y bailes por las calles', 'tropa impetuosa', 'festín, banquete'.`
>
> 1. m. desus. Burla, chasco. Dar como, o un como.

Mientras que la segunda es aquella que todos pensaríamos como principal:

> [**como**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9)<sup>2</sup>
>   `Del lat. quomŏdo.`
>   Puede escribirse con acento en acep. 6.
>
> 1. adv. relat. En el que, en el cual o en que. U. con los antecedentes nominales manera, modo, forma o con los antecedentes adverbiales así, tal e igual. Me encantaba la manera como sonreía. Lo hice tal como me dijiste.

y así hasta 18 acepciones del uso de *como* como adverbio, conjunción y preposición, así como las locuciones en desuso *como quier que* y *en como*.

¿Qué lógica utiliza la RAE para colocar las entradas? ¿No debería en algún momento permutar el orden para primar el *como* conocido?

Comment: Es posible que ordenen sustantivos antes que otras categorías gramaticales. ej. [*ese*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GOaPBVM|GOeWVLy)

Comment: relacionado: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/85067/112436

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que la respuesta viene en las [Advertencias para el uso del diccionario](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/que-contiene/item-numero-2):

> Cuando se produce una confluencia entre varios lemas de distinto origen etimológico, estos se distinguen mediante el empleo de un superíndice.

Y sigue:

> **El orden de los artículos distinguidos por el superíndice depende de la mayor o menor antigüedad de su incorporación al Diccionario.**

Luego añade:

> **El superíndice también diferencia los infinitivos verbales de las formas sustantivadas derivadas de ellos**. En este caso, el artículo correspondiente al sustantivo, que no lleva etimología, aparece siempre en segundo lugar. P. ej.:
>
> > amanecer<sup>1</sup>. (De lat. hisp. *manescĕre*). intr. impers. Empezar a aparecer la luz del día. *Amanece a las ocho. Amanece nublado*. [...]
> >
> > amanecer<sup>2</sup>. m. Tiempo durante el cual amanece. *El amanecer de un día de mayo*. [...]

---

En el caso concreto de *como*, el Mapa de diccionarios muestra entradas de ambos ya en 1780. Y de hecho, el NTLLE nos muestra entradas ya de Nebrija en 1495: *Como comparando.ut.quemadmodum*. Y así lo mismo con Covarrubias (1611) y los otros.